# I'm seeing bright lights at the end of this tunnel in Seiklus, should I be worried?

Tags: seiklus

I have been making some progress in Seiklus, finding cool stuff, and generally having a good time. Then I check out the map(once I read the instructions to *find* the map button,) and find that there are a number of blinking lights on certain area blocks:

[image: blinking lights]

They alternate between white and black, and they seem to me to appear in a rather random fashion. Is this a sign of some secretes I'm totally missing, or something else I should be worried about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally realized what the blinking lights mean.

While progressing through the game, I noticed that the lights did go away after a while. I finally figured out that the blinking lights are for areas that still contain elusive white orbs. So they act as reminders to return and search places that have missed.